# Bitbucket Pipeline doesn't show the full output of Yarn build

Tags: yarnpkg, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline with a `yarn build` command. The problem is that the output always misses the last lines:

```
+ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.
File sizes after gzip:
```

It is suppose to have more lines after `File sizes after gzip:`.

My `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`:

```yaml
image: node:latest

pipelines:
  branches:
    staging:
      steps:
        - step:
          name: Build
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - yarn install
            - yarn build
```

The biggest issue is when `yarn build` errors. Because I don't see the last lines, I can't tell why it failed. When this happens, I have to manually run `yarn build` on my local machine to see the full logs, which is not the best solution.

When I run the same `yarn build` command on my machine, I get the full logs:

```
❯ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  383.56 kB  build/static/js/main.a23388a2.js
  13.39 kB   build/static/css/main.06459f93.css
  1.79 kB    build/static/js/787.44808443.chunk.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  yarn global add serve
  serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment

Done in 19.59s.
```

I found that the output is truncated on many other commands, not just `yarn build`. I created a simple `echo "Hello, World!"` that is executed remotely on a server via `atlassian/ssh-run`, and the "Hello, World!" message was truncated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution: refresh the page.

tl;dr;
This is a three-year bug (and counting) on the BitBucket interface:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-18574

It seems their interface doesn't work properly getting the results in real-time, but the logs are properly saved and can be retrieved by reloading the page.